# Saga Event channels not emitting a callback

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, redux-saga

Learning Saga eventchannels for listening to custom events and couldn't able to fix the issue .

issue:
startlistner() function is not get invoked from root function when calling

```
const channel = yield call(startlistner);
```

fullcode

```
import { eventChannel } from "redux-saga";
import { take, fork, call } from "@redux-saga/core/effects";

export default function handleclick() {
root().next();
}

function* root() {
const channel = yield call(startlistner);
while (true) {
const { data } = yield take(channel);
console.log("while");
 }
}

function startlistner() {
console.log("da");
const channel = eventChannel(emmiter => {
emmiter({ data: null });
return () => {};
});
}
```

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

> Saga Event channels not emitting a callback

In your `startlistner()` you didn't return the event channel.

```
function startlistner() {
  const channel = eventChannel(emmiter => {
    emmiter({ data: null }); // for emitting action
    return () => {};         // for unsubscribe
  });

  return channel;            // return event channel to caller.
}
```